# What is the number of API calls I've made?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an API call to get events from my profile with the default limit as 25.

```
/me/events
```

I would like to know, when I make this single call, it gives me a set of results(25 events) with 3 pager. So I'm trying to calculate the number of API's involving in this process. Is it only 1, or more than that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call that endpoint once, it will be one API call returning 25 elements. If you use the "next" link to get the next 25 elements, it will be two API calls, and so on. In order to get through 3 pages > 3 API calls. Not sure how to explain this, but if you call the API it is one API call (surprise).

Btw, you can also increase the limit so you don´t need 3 API calls for more than 50 entries: `/me/events?limit=100` - this would be 1 API call to get the first 100 entries.

Comment: there is no calculation. if you call the api, then it´s one api call. not sure what you want to know exactly? if you use the limit parameter with a value of 100, you can get up to 100 entries with one api call.

Comment: no, of course it´s one api call returning 25 elements

Comment: I would like to know what is the maximum limit for limit parameter for event object?

Comment: there is no specific maximum, in general a limit higher than 100 is pointless. it also increases the callback time, and you should never need to get ALL results. implement a useful paging mechanism so the user can "load more" if he wants to, for example.